# Visual Studio Code — Insert Newline at the End of Files

Tags: visual-studio-code, newline

When saving a file using Visual Studio Code, a newline is not automatically added to the end of the file, causing all sorts of [potential issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline).

How can I append a newline automatically in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: It does indeed cause all sorts of potential issues, but it is also a beginner mistake of compiler writers, parser writers, and other system writers not to handle it properly.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen having a line break as the last character in a file does not just prevent issues, it's in the POSIX standard, so tools are allowed to assume it.

Answer (score 467, accepted):

There are two easy methods to make Visual Studio Code insert a new line at the end of files:

### Method I

1. Open Visual Studio Code and go to **File (Code if using a Mac) -> Preferences -> Settings**; you should now be viewing a settings page
2. Enter '**insert final newline**' in to the search bar
3. Select the checkbox under the heading '**Files: Insert Final Newline**' in the '**Workspace Settings**' and/or '**User Settings**' tab(s) as required

[image: Settings Page with 'Files: Insert Final Newline' checkbox selected]

### Method II

1. Open Visual Studio Code and go to **File (Code if using a Mac) -> Preferences -> Settings**; you should now be viewing a settings page
2. Open the JSON settings page by clicking the **{}** icon at the top right of the page
3. Enter '**files.insertFinalNewline**' in to the search bar of the JSON settings page
4. Either

   - Click on the white 'edit pen' on the left hand side of the line containing the `files.insertFinalNewline` JSON key and select `True`

   *or*

   - Copy the line containing the `files.insertFinalNewline` JSON key, paste it into the right hand side JSON file under the **'User Settings'** and/or **'Workspace Settings'** tab(s) as required, and set its value to `true`

[image: User Settings JSON with <code>files.insertFinalNewline</code> set to <code>true</code>]

### Final Result

In either your **User Settings** or **Workspace Settings** JSON file, you should have a line reading `"files.insertFinalNewline": true`, within the provided curly braces ({ }). Additionally, in the **Settings** page, the checkbox under the heading '**Files: Insert Final Newline**' will be selected.

Visual Studio Code will now add an empty line to the end of files when being saved, if there isn't already one.

Comment: Does this ever result in extra newlines if the file already has newlines at the end?

Comment: @AaronFranke I have never seen that behaviour. For me, it only adds a newline if there isn't already one. If you are having this issue, perhaps check your final lines don't contain some formatting that you aren't noticing.

Comment: You can also define per language type: `"[javascript]": {"files.insertFinalNewline": true}`

Comment: @AaronFranke No, but if you already have extra newlines, this setting doesn't cap the extras. This is sad.

Comment: @Lawrence but there is also a setting for that `"files.trimFinalNewlines": true`

Comment: My VSCode is suddenly adding a blank line at the end of file when I save. I have disabled all options to add a new line. I even uninstalled the `Prettier` extension. But it still keeps adding a new blank line at the end of file when I press `ctrl + s`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: @0x0147k3r I have not had to restart VS Code after applying the files.insertFinalNewline setting on any of the machines I have used.

Comment: @LJH for me I needed to restart, I removed the comment  as I see it was of no use to anyone else "thumbs up"

Comment: Is there a way to achieve similar result in Visual Studio (not Code)?

Answer (score 145):

I have placed a screen capture below showing how to make Visual Studio Code insert a newline at the end of files. This will also serve as a useful place to link to in code reviews when saying "You need to do this and resubmit".

[image: screen capture of settings change]

Comment: Awesome, I also recommend ticking the checkbox `Trim Final Newlines` in case there are multiple newlines to reduce it to just 1. I also like `Trim Trailing Whitespace` although some markdown requires two trailing spaces, I avoid that particular markdown syntax because I really want to trim it in code files.

Answer (score 16):

VS Code `1.76.2`.

1. `CMD` + `Shift` + `P`
2. Type `user settings JSON`

[image: Setting search]

3. In `settings.json` add

```
"files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"files.trimFinalNewlines": true
```

OR

---

1. `CMD` + `,`
2. Type in the *search settings* `newline`

[image: Setting search]

3. Check `Insert Final Newline` and `Trim Final Newlines`

[image: Files settings]

Answer (score 3):

While editing PHP files, something was deleting the newline at the end of the file.
In my case it turned out to be the HTML format (html.format.endWithNewline), I believe because of the Emmet extension. (see attached images)

[image: emmet settings]
[image: html format "End with newline" setting]

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and solved it by uninstalling a save while typing extension that I had installed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

every type of files has it's own settings so if you go to the settings you will find for example for blade:
Blade: New Line
then a check box to insert or not an empty line at the end of file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).